# How to install gitleaks in windows?

Tags: github

How to install **gitleak** in windows? I tried few ways but didn't work.
https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks

Comment: Please read [ask]: _what_ did you try, and what _specifically_ didn't work?

Comment: It's not clear which tag, if any, should be used on this question, but [tag:git] and [tag:gitlab] are *definitely* wrong and [tag:github] is almost certainly wrong. See their "about this tag" text to see why.

Answer (score 7):

you can download it dirctly from the source code in Github compiled

---

1 - Go to Github Source Code  `https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks`

2 - Open releases and you will find
[compiled gitleaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAEgU.png)

3 -if your system 64 download **gitleaks_8.2.7_windows_x64.zip**

4 -if your system 64 download **gitleaks_8.2.7_windows_x32.zip**

5- unzip compressed file and you will find **gitleaks.exe**

Comment: direct link to releases page https://github.com/zricethezav/gitleaks/releases